# Error while loading gif image source

Tags: android, gif

I tried executing the following line to load gif image, programatically.
gifInputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.image);
But, studio used to indicate an error near "R.drawable.image".

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, or rather hack around to my issue. I just added "+" symbol. So, the line looks like this now...
gifInputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(+R.drawable.image);

AndroidStudio doesn't show any error now.

Answer (score 0):

it required raw file not drawable.

Please create `res/raw/` directory and move your file in the raw directory.

after then:-

```
context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfilename)
```